# Image won't show up in IE8, only in Chrome or Firefox or IE9

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have been stuck on this for a long time.

This page has several image icons to the left of the text content. These images get loaded perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9, but in IE8, they don't get loaded. IE8 is perfectly fine loading the actual image link directly, so I know it's not a fault with the image itself.

In fact, this only happens on that one page. The other pages are able to load images just fine.

Can anyone explain this huge mystery? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem seems to be the css rule

```
.entry-content IMG
{
    max-width:97.5%
}
```

When I remove it the images get displayed... do not know why this happens =/

**edit**

IE8 seems to have a problem with img tags where the width attribute and the css "max-width" attribute is set... maybe just remove on of them.